# Applying CSS by Component's displayName?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

Calling all experts!

I am trying to add a class to disable all element's descendants to be read only, the style is fine, but it doesn't applied to all descendants nor any:

```
#ComponentDisplayName * {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The element is a `component` that I want to have the above style by `displayName` as `div` id, like so:

```
import * as readOnly from './Permission.scss';

<div
    id={component.type.displayName}
    className={readOnly[component.type.displayName]}
>
    {React.createElement(component, {
        ...component.className
    })}
</div>
```

The output HTML:

[image]

The final result should show the component has the style cascade to all its children.

**Is that even possible?**

Thanks in advance to all of the participants.

Comment: This looks possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: I think the outcome answers the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - The style appears on the div wrapper when I inspect the chrome dev-tools. `<div id="GeneralInfo" class="Permission__GeneralInfo__3gx1M">` But no effect is taking place..

Comment: Can you update the question with the rendered HTML? (only the div and it's children please)

Comment: Try adding “display: block” to the child elements

Comment: @Shino - sorry, doesn't work either

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I have updated my comment with your request, I can also see the children (so no problem with that). However their style didn't changed.

Comment: (put the HTML in the question, not a comment. also maybe include some of the Permissions scss)

Comment: @evolutionxbox - This is the only style I have in `Permissions.scss`

Comment: So in your scss, does `#GeneralInfo *` not work?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - HTML output updated, And yes it doesn't apply all the css to all descendant elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I don't need to use id attribute after all. It is sufficient to define class rule as the `displayName`:

```
.ComponentDisplayName * {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then you can pick the style with the component's `displayName` as follow:

```
import * as readOnly from './Permission.scss';

<div className={readOnly[component.type.displayName]}>
    {React.createElement(component, {
        ...component.className
    })}
</div>
```

Finally, the styles will apply to all descendant elements of the component.

Comment: Glad it worked, but it's strange that a class would work, but an ID didn't.

Comment: I doubt it. Consider testing it using only the output html and the compiled css.